# dynamically set an instance property / memoized attribute in python?

Tags: python, monkeypatching

I have an existing example class in Python 2.7x

```
class Example(object):
    a = None
    b = None
    c = None
```

and an existing instance

```
anInstance = Example()
anInstance.a = 100
anInstance.b = 200
anInstance.c = 300
```

I've been refactoring/cleaning some code, and it's now known that `anInstance.c` is an expensive operation that is rarely used.

in a perfect world I would just do this :

```
class Example(object):
    _c = None
    @property
    def c(self):
        if self._c is not None:
           self._c = DO EXPENSIVE STUFF HERE
        return self._c
```

The problem is that I can't change `class Example` right now.  [ So the quickfix would be to set it as a function, and change every `obj.c` to `obj.c()` ]

A far as I know there isn't any way that I can dynamically assign a property / memoization unless I alter the object.  Is that understanding correct ?  I'm expecting to be disappointed here, I just want the confirmation.

Comment: Surely if `obj.c` is not a property then it's being computed in `Example.__init__`, in which case you have to modify `Example`? Otherwise why would making it a property change anything?

Comment: This is a portion of code from a webapp which handles state for users.  __init__ just sets up placeholder values.  The state is conditionally computed on only a handful of requests; this particular attribute is required even fewer times.    I didn't write/design this portion.  I'm trying to fix it.  As much as I'd like to gut it all, that is not an option.

Answer (score 4):

You can alter python classes after the fact:

```
@property
def c(self):
    if self._c is None:
        self._c = DO EXPENSIVE STUFF HERE
    return self._c

Example.c = c
Example._c = None
```

Now you've added a property `c` to your class, as well as add a `_c` attribute.

You may need to override any existing methods on the class that assume they can assign to `self.c`, of course.

The process of dynamically adding or replacing attributes of objects is often referred to as [Monkey Patching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch).

Comment: Of course, if it is possible to alter the code that instantiates `Example`, it would be better to inherit from `Example` and create subclass instances instead.

Comment: @Marcin: at which point you need to monkey patch the code that imports `Example`.

Comment: Not if you can alter it without monkeypatching. And if there is a limited number of places where `Example` instances are created, then it is sufficient just to alter those.

Comment: I can't monkeypatch Example.  I specifically need to affect the `instance` , not `class`.  In the application, the `Example` class is used in a handful of places to store bits of configuration and state data.  Monkeypatching the class would potentially cause more harm/work than adjusting the code that inherits from example.  The only real way to do this with Monkeypatching would be to override `Example.__getattr__` - which I'd rather not do.

Comment: In that case you are stuck, because you cannot add properties **or** a `__getattr__` hook to instances. As descriptors, properties only get invoked correctly when looked up on the class, and the dunder hooks such as `__getattr__` are *only* looked up on the type (so classes for instances).